# Problem with rotating cylinder with camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a first-person character controller for Unity3D, everything is working however I can't rotate the cylindrical player model while moving, the camera rotates but the cylinder remains facing the same direction until the key is released. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;
    public Camera cam;
    public Transform playerBody;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    float xRotation = 0f;
    float yRotation = 0f;
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;
    float multiplier = 0.01f;

    private void Start()
    {
       Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
    MyInput();

     playerBody.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,yRotation, 0);
     cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
    }

    void MyInput()
    {
     mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
     mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

     xRotation -= mouseY * sensX;
     yRotation += mouseX * sensY;
     xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you check if you set the players local rotation to Quaternion.Euler(xRotation,0,0) or any variations like that

Comment: I only see code here for a playerBody and a camera. Where are you trying to do something with a cylinder??